# Is Cypress compatible with Salesforce?

Tags: cypress

After I log in, the domain changes and it doesn't do anything else that my script tells it to do. Is it the case that you just can't do anything once the domain changes? I can't quite tell from the documentation. I know it says that it can't navigate to a second domain, but I haven't seen where it says it can't do anything on a second domain.

Additionally, did Cypress used to login to Salesforce with cy.request()? Because currently Salesforce doesn't allow for logging in by sending a request with parameters.

```
cy.visit('https://test.salesforce.com');
        cy.get('.username').type(username)
        cy.get('.password').type(password)        
        cy.get('#Login').click()
```

This is my code for logging in.

Answer (score -1):

Hi you can use **Session** in cypress in order to Cache and restore cookies, localStorage, and sessionStorage

Just create a command in ./support/command.js

You can read the documentation here https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/session#Syntax

Comment: Have you done Cypress testing for Salesforce before?